# Need to delete cases and need to update contacts

Tags: apex, force.com

I need to delete cases of users who are inactive, and need to update the contact name to XXX of those cases parents. I wrote a batch class, but it's not working, and throwing an error at invalid void method at "objcaseIds.add(obj.Contact);"

---

```
global class casedelete implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

        Map<Id ,User> users = new Map<Id ,User>([Select id from User where Profile.Name='merchdise' AND IsActive= false AND LastLoginDate<NEXT_N_YEARS:5]);

        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id from Case where OwnerId IN :users.keyset()]);

    }



    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
    {



             List<Id> objcaseIds = new List<Id>();

             for(Case obj : Scope){
                 objcaseIds.add(obj.Contact);
             } 

             Map<Id, Contact> objconId = new Map<Id, Contact>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id in :objcaseIds]);

             for(Case objB : Scope){
                  Conctact objA = objconId.get(objB.Contact);
                  objA.Name ='XXXX';
                  objconId.put(objB.Contact, objA);
             }
             update objconId.values();
             delete objcaseIds ;





    }



    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Case.Contact` is an `sObject` of type `Contact`, but you're trying to add it to a `Set<Id>`. In this case, you need to use `ContactId` instead:

```
objcaseIds.add(obj.ContactId);
```

You will also need to remember to add this field to your query or you'll get a different error. You make a similar mistake later on in your code as well that you'll need to fix.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the reply but i am getting another error called "Error: Compile Error: Invalid loop variable type expected SObject was Case at line 20 column 14  for(Case obj : Scope){"

Comment: @Thelearner Yes, you have a number of errors in your code. This one should be easy to figure out.

Comment: If you dont mind , can you help me out please over here, i am trying alot but not able to sort out.

Comment: @Thelearner What have you tried so far? What do you think the problem might be? I understand that you're new to Apex Code, but critical thinking is important. You should be able to figure this out.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help , its got solved it now working fine